# Composer error while trying to upgrade to Yii 2.0.15

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I tried to update my Yii but I receive this message:

```
[alexandre@Mac-mini-de-Alexandre:gestao_web (master)] php composer.phar require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.15" --update-with-dependencies
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Installation request for yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip (locked at 2.0.12, required as ~2.0.0) -> satisfiable by yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip[2.0.12].
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.15 requires bower-asset/inputmask ~3.2.2 | ~3.3.5 -> satisfiable by yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip[2.0.13].
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.15.1 requires bower-asset/inputmask ~3.2.2 | ~3.3.5 -> satisfiable by yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip[2.0.13].
- Conclusion: don't install yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip 2.0.13
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 ~2.0.15 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.15, 2.0.15.1].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
[alexandre@Mac-mini-de-Alexandre:gestao_web (master)] ./yii
This is Yii version 2.0.12.2.
```

This is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Application Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "application template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.7",        
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-resource-manager-component": "*",
        "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
        "boundstate/yii2-mailgun": "*",
        "e96/yii2-mailgun-mailer": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried change composer to it:

```
"yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.12"
```

But I have the same error.

Does anyone know what this problem might be? How can I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a `--update-with-all-dependencies` switch in this case:

```
php composer.phar require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.15" --update-with-all-dependencies
```

> **--update-with-dependencies**: Also update dependencies of the newly required packages, except those that are root requirements.
>   **--update-with-all-dependencies**: Also update dependencies of the newly required packages, including those that are root requirements.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

---

BTW: you should really replace all those `*` in your `composer.json` with real constraint - every update may break your app.